# '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'. form.is_valid

Tags: python, django

I have error when try to create or update Category model. When I try save or edit with debuger this error does not arise and model saved.

[image]

views.py

```
def create(request):
    model = Category()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST, instance=model)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/cabinet/category/')
    else:
        form = CategoryForm(instance=model)
    return render(request, 'cabinet/category/create.html', {'form': form})
```

form.py

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=TextInputCustom())

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name']
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 4):

Oh, I find error reason. Just add `max_length=255` to `models.CharField(unique=True)` in models.py